# Setting OpenLayers line labels by angle?

Tags: openlayers, labeling, style, features

I want to write labels near linestring features on my map. I calculated but it works wrong.

My layer style function is like following:

```
layerFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceFeatures,
    style: function(feature, resolution){


        let first = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        let last = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[1];


        let rotation = -Math.atan2((last[1] - first[1]),(last[0] - first[0]));

                    var style = new ol.style.Style({
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({
             color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
           }),
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: '#3399CC',
             width: 1.25
           }),
           text: new ol.style.Text({
             font: '14px Verdana',
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#000000'
             }),
             stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#f2f',
              width: 1
            })
           })
        })

        let label = feature.get("properties").name;

        style.getText().setRotation(rotation)
                    style.getText().setText(label)

        return [style];

    }
})
```

The directions of labels are wrong. It shold be readable direction, but some of them are reversed.

and my [working code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/y3rnwsz1/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using atan would give better results than atan2:

```
let rotation = -Math.atan((last[1] - first[1])/(last[0] - first[0]));
```

You could also switch to a more recent version of OpenLayers and use the

```
placement: 'line',
```

option in `ol.style.Text` (introduced in version 4) which avoids having to set rotation

Comment: how can I set the offsetx and ofsety? I want to set text 10px up of the line.

Comment: `textBaseline: 'bottom', offsetY: -10,` works correctly with version 4, but with the version in your jsfiddle the offset doesn't take account of rotation.